# Nested loop construction

Tags: java, nested-loops

This is part of my homework. All I need is a bit of advice. I need to write some nested loop constructs, to print the following:

```
"122333444455555"

"+**+++****+++++"

"--***++++-----******+++++++"
```

Here is my code to print the first set of symbols

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<6;++i)
    {
        for(j=1;j<i+1;++j)
        {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine. I'm just having trouble figuring out the second and third set of symbols. 
Apologies for my lack of experience, I'm fairly new to Java.

Comment: what is the rule for the second and third sets?

Comment: you could use a switch case for the second and third to change the char

Comment: Switch with modulo in second example is mod 2, and in third is mod 3. Modulo should be done on `i` variable. As well you could use ASCII table `+` and `*`, are next to each other. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i < 6; ++i) {
        for (j = 1; j < i + 1; ++j) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            for (j = 1; j < i + 1; ++j){
            System.out.print("+");
            }
        } else {
            for (j = 1; j < i + 1; ++j){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (i = 2; i < 8; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 1) {
            for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j){
                System.out.print("+");
            }
        } else if (i % 3 == 2) {
            for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j){
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        } else {
            for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Cycle #1:**
You have to print out numbers from one to five and each number N has to be printed out N times.

```
for (i = 1; i < 6; ++i) { // this would set `i` to numbers from 1-5

for (j = 1; j < i + 1; ++j) { // for each cycle (next number) it prints 
//it out N times where N is the cycle number. 1 is the first cycle,
//2 is the second and so on.
```

**Cycle #2:**
Same problem but instead of printing out number of the cycle you have to print out + or * based on if the cycle number is odd or even.

To check if the number is even you can use:

```
int number = 1;
if(number % 2 == 0){ // is true if the number is even
```

This checks whats the remainder from the division of `number` by two.

**Cycle #3:**
Same as #2 but you start from the second cycle, not from the first and you check for the remainder after division by 3.

Comment: I really like how you've broken down each of the codes in your explanation, really makes for easier understanding. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is:

```
final String[] arr = {"*", "+"};
```

And in your *inner* loop:

```
System.out.print(arr[i % 2]);
```

The [`%`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (Modulo) operator is responsible of the switches between `*` and `+` symbols:

For *even* `i` it'll be `*`, otherwise it'll be `+`.

---

Output: `"+**+++****+++++"`.

(Regarding the second output, I'll not show you the solution, but it's very similar to this one once you understand it).

Comment: I can't understand.. third sequence has also char '-'. Arr provides just two char..

Comment: @Velthune This solution only for your first sequence. If you understand the modulo operator, you can have a new array and construct a similar output.

Comment: Wasn't clear, for me at least! (: I think the real problem is the third sequence.

Comment: @Velthune It's from `_`, `*` and `+`. `_` is printed twice, then `+` 3 times, then `*` four times.. Almost the same logic as the previous symbols expect that it begins from 2 times the first symbol.

Comment: Also I think it's the most "organized" way to do this, it's a good practice to use the `%` operator when patterns are involved.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, the third set is composed by sequence of "-*+" so:

```
String sequence = "-*+";
String s = "+**+++****+++++";
int seqI = 0;
for(i=0; i != s.size(); ++i) {
  for(j=0; j < i+2; ++j) {
    System.out.print(sequence[seqI]);
  }
  if(seqI < sequence.size()) {
    ++seqI;
  } else {
    seqI = 0;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function like this:

```
public static char Output(int i, int mode)
{
     if (mode == 1)
     {
        return (char) i;
     }
     else if (mode == 2)
     {
         if (i % 2 == 0)
         {
             return '+';
         }
         else
         {
             return '*';
         }
     }
     else if (mode == 3)
     {
         if (i % 3 == 0)
         {
             return '-';
         }
         else if (i % 3 == 1)
         {
             return '*';
         }
         else
         {
             return '+';
         }
     }
}
```

And use it just like:

```
for (int mode = 1 ; mode < 4 ; mode++)
{
    for (int i = 1 ; i < 6 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < i + (int)(mode / 3) ; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(Output(i, mode));
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Yes! Actually my code is hard to read, but if you try to read it, you will learn something more than other answers!

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up